# Replicating the dplyr `any_of()` functionality in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I can easily apply the function `as.integer` to all columns in a `tibble` that match a column name supplied to `any_of()`:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(x = c("1","2","3"), y = c("4","5","6"), z = c("7","8","9"))
cols <- c("x","y","z","a","b","c")
dplyr::mutate(df, dplyr::across(dplyr::any_of(cols), as.integer))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     7
2     2     5     8
3     3     6     9
```

Can this functionality be easily replicated in `data.table`? I would like to avoid the copy-on-modify associated with `tidyverse` (and the rest of R):

```
tracemem(df)
[1] "<0000026B195C4090>"

dplyr::mutate(df, dplyr::across(dplyr::any_of(cols), as.integer))

tracemem[0x0000026b195c4090 -> 0x0000026b196d1110]: <Anonymous> eval_select_impl <Anonymous> across_setup <Anonymous> .Call <Anonymous> withCallingHandlers mutate_cols mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b195c4090 -> 0x0000026b197d44d0]: new_data_frame vec_data dplyr_vec_data as.list dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d44d0 -> 0x0000026b197d4480]: new_data_frame dplyr_vec_data as.list dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d4480 -> 0x0000026b197d43e0]: as.list.data.frame as.list dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d43e0 -> 0x0000026b197d3d50]: new_data_frame dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d3d50 -> 0x0000026b197d3d00]: new_data_frame dplyr_new_data_frame dplyr_reconstruct dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d3d00 -> 0x0000026b197d3b20]: dplyr_reconstruct.data.frame dplyr_reconstruct_dispatch dplyr_reconstruct dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d3b20 -> 0x0000026b197d3ad0]: dplyr_reconstruct.data.frame dplyr_reconstruct_dispatch dplyr_reconstruct dplyr_col_modify.data.frame dplyr_col_modify mutate.data.frame <Anonymous> 
tracemem[0x0000026b197d3ad0 -> 0x0000026b197d36c0]: lapply tbl_subset_row [.tbl_df [ do.call head.data.frame head as.data.frame trunc_mat format.tbl format paste0 <Anonymous> print.tbl <Anonymous>
```

Can this be implemented in `data.table` using modify-by-reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `set` and `intersect`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(v in intersect(cols, names(df))) {
    set(df, i = NULL, j = v, value = as.integer(df[[v]]))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find out the common columns using `intersect` and change those columns to integer using `.SDcols`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
correct_cols <- intersect(cols, names(df))

df[, (correct_cols) := lapply(.SD,as.integer), .SDcols = correct_cols]
df

#   x y z
#1: 1 4 7
#2: 2 5 8
#3: 3 6 9

str(df)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: int  1 2 3
# $ y: int  4 5 6
# $ z: int  7 8 9
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```